# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n \sum_{j=0}^{n} x^j Pr\{ Y_n=j\} = \frac{1-F(t)}{(1-t)(1-F(xt))} $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Assume state $0$ is positive recurrent. We take the initial state to be $0$. Let $\{W_n\}$, $n=1,\ldots,n$ denote successive recurrence times which are of course independent and identically distributed random variables with finite mean and with a generating function
$$ F(t)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} t^k \ Pr\{W_1=k\}, \  \  \ |t|<1$$

Define $Y_n$ as the time of the last visit to state $0$ before the time $n$. With this I have to prove that

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n \sum_{j=0}^{n} x^j Pr\{ Y_n=j\} = \frac{1-F(t)}{(1-t)(1-F(xt))} $$

For this I have to prove this
$$Pr\{Y_n=j \}=Pr\{W_1+\cdots+W_{N_n}=j\} \cdot q_{n-j}$$
where $q_i=Pr\{W_1>i\}$ and $N_n$ is the number of visits to state $0$ in the first $n$ trials. (As a hint of my teacher)

Ok, first I tried to analyze $Pr\{Y_n=j \}$:

$$ Pr\{Y_n=j \}= Pr\{X_j=0, X_k \ne 0, j+1 \leq k \leq n \}$$
$$ = Pr\{ X_j=0, W_1 > n-j \} = Pr \{  W_1 > n-j | X_j=0\} Pr\{X_j=0\} $$
$$= Pr\{X_j=0 \} Pr\{W_1 > n-j \} = Pr\{X_j=0 \} q_{n-j}  $$

and here I stuck, I think this $= q_{n-j} \sum_{k=0}^j Pr\{W_1+\cdots+W_k=j\}$ but i can not prove that $Pr\{Y_n=j \}=Pr\{W_1+\cdots+W_{N_n}=j\} \cdot q_{n-j}$

Is this correct? Could someone help me to conclude this problem, pls.

Please some help....

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Think intuitively: $Y_n=j$ if and only if the time of the last visit to (by time $n$) $0$ (which is exactly $W_1+W_2+...+W_{N_n}$ is $j$ and the next visit to $0$ occurs after $(n-j)$ unit of time.

Comment: Ok, so:$$Pr\{Y_n=j \}= Pr\{X_j=0, X_k \ne 0, j+1 \leq k < n \}$$
$$ = Pr\{ X_j=0, W_1 > n-j \} = Pr \{  W_1 > n-j | X_j=0\} Pr\{X_j=0\} $$
$$= Pr\{X_j=0 \} Pr\{W_1 > n-j \} = Pr\{X_j=0 \} q_{n-j}  $$
$$=Pr\{W_1+\cdots+W_{N_n}=j\} \cdot q_{n-j}$$

Comment: Now trying using that $$Pr\{Y_n=j\}=Pr\{W_1+\cdots+W_{N_n}=k\}\cdot q_{n-j}$$, Can you give me a hint to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n \sum_{j=0}^{n} x^j Pr\{ Y_n=j\} = \frac{1-F(t)}{(1-t)(1-F(xt))} $, How can I get the sums ? I have thinking and I believe that I need to find a way to interchange the limits of the sum because I have $\sum_n \sum_j \sum_k t^nx^j Pr\{W_1+\cdots+W_k=j\}$ but Can you help me pls?